# pdftoppm add output folder

Tags: 12.04

I want the output image in some other folder

```
pdftoppm -png file.pdf prefix
```

with this command I can generate image properly

But is it possible to get output in some other folder

Comment: `cd some/other/folder; pdftoppm -png "$OLDPWD/file.pdf" prefix`?

Comment: thx. working. Tricky.....

Comment: If the answer beow helped you, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Answer (score 0):

Via a path and name as prefix

```
pdftoppm -png file.pdf ../out
```

or

```
pdftoppm -png file.pdf ~/out
```

or

```
pdftoppm -png file.pdf $HOME/out
```

and so on…

Comment: This does not work man...Try this command in line nothing will happen

Comment: He man, it works. Maybe you just tell me what command you mean and what does not.